# How to access outer function observable in inner function in viewmodel?

Tags: knockout.js

I am having a main function and sub function inside that, like this:

```
var main= function () {
    var self = this;
    self.value1 = ko.observable("");
     var data =   self.value1();   
     self.revaluate = ko.computed(function(){ 
     data = self.self.value1(); // i am overwriting 
     });

    function inner(i1,i2)
    {
        var self= this ;

        self.id1=ko.observable(i1);
        self.id2=ko.observable(i2);
        self.value2 = ko.observable("");

        self.visibility = ko.computed(function() {
            if (data == 1) {return true;}
            else {false;}
        });
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new main());
```

I need the `value1` value inside my `inner` function that should be dynamic.

I tried storing it in a variable and accessing it, but it's not gonna solve my case as there is a scenario where `self.visibility` won't fire at all and update dynamically.

Onload I get an updated `value1` so everything will work, but I have a button "goto next stage", and onclick of that button I am updating the status, i.e `self.value1(2)`. At this point `self.visibility` should update as there is change in `value1`.

I tried to show what I need in a simple example, but in reality there's some more complex looping going on.

Any clue will be great.

Answer (score 0):

For your computed to update when self.value1 updates you actually have to use it inside computed function

```
self.visibility = ko.computed(function(){
        if( self.value1() == 1)
            {return true;}
        else
           { return false;}
         });
        }
```

Main reason why your computed didn't work is because you were using ***data*** to calculate the computed which is a simple JS variable, that is why it updated only onload, ***data*** never actually reevaluated, so your computed never got updated. What you need to use is an ***ko.observable*** for computed to update properly!

One other note: I don't see that you've used any variable from inner function in your computed. If that is the case in your real example than you can simply transfer the computed to main function.

Edit: As I don't have a working code, and don't know how are you using this inner function I can't create a working example just point to problems. self.value1 will have scope problems but you should be able to overcome this, try passing it as a variable, use global variable... Whichever works for you

Comment: Don't forget to execute `value1` as it's an observable. In addition, a problem from the question that you copied along: the `else` bit does not *return* anything, it just "executes" `false` as a statement (and the function will end up returning `undefined` which is falsy, so it's not really noticed probably).

Comment: check my edit . `data never actually reevaluated` now it will but still same issue i cant get my updated 'data' inside the inner function on run .

Comment: `icepick` in your code you mentioned `if(self.value1 ==1` which wont work it give undefined because of scope issues .

Comment: Ok there are scope issues, but I still see no reason for that code to be in the inner function.
You've gained nothing by reevaluating data. Data is still a simple JS variable. Visibility will not trigger compute because you've not used any observable inside computed function. You need to make data observable to use it like that

Comment: yes mate thats what i am looking  for but how , can you hint me . As there are scope issue how to get it done . `I still see no reason` i already tried it gave me error . reason is simple `inner` function having `var self=this` and you trying to access `self.value1()` which is wrong as there is no observable in scope . hope you got me

Comment: simpler: `return self.value1() === 1`.  Also, just pass `this` as a second parameter after the function to `ko.computed` and then you can do `this.value1()`.  That saves you from having to stick `self` into the closure.

Comment: `Milimetric`  any snippet or edit in my code will do fine  . `Icepick` i been doing the way u suggested but as i mentioned variable will update if change is status but how to make my computed which is `inner` function to fire

Comment: yeah i got the solution . if is declare `var self1=this;` inside subfunction i can access main `self` . if u can update this line in your code i can mark as answer . cheers