# How to do a validation to find duplicate entries ? knockout

Tags: jquery, validation, knockout.js

I have a scenario when i dynamically add multiple rows using `template` way i need to write down a validation if `CountryCode` (which should be unique) having same value in two or more dynamically generated rows .

**working fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/73/

Well i am thinking can this be possible using custom validation code but i am not sure how to proceed i mean how to compare in `validator` function inside `validation`  .

And the same can be done on click of `submit` in save function like we run a foreach each aganist every row `code` and do it but is it a good practice .

**My view model:**

```
 function Phone() {
        var self = this;
        self.Code = ko.observable(""); // this should be unique 
        self.Date = ko.observable("");
        self.PhoneNumber = ko.observable("");

        self.Validation = ko.validatedObservable([
            self.Code.extend({ required: true }),
            self.Date.extend({ required: true }),
            self.PhoneNumber.extend({ required: true })
        ]);
         } 

    function PhoneViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.PhoneList = ko.observableArray([new Phone()]);
        self.remove = function () {
            self.PhoneList.remove(this);
        };
        self.add = function () {

            self.PhoneList.push(new Phone()); // i add on click of add button 
        };
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new PhoneViewModel());
```

Any suggestions are appreciated .

Comment: Please don't keep the entire code that belongs to your question on external sites. Copy it here, keep the link to jsFiddle.

Comment: tomalak suggestion taken . thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, in your set-up:

```
// straight from https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation
ko.validation.rules['mustEqual'] = {
    validator: function (val, otherVal) {
        return val === otherVal;
    },
    message: 'The field must equal {0}'
};
```

Later, in `PhoneViewModel`:

```
self.codesAreUniuqe = ko.computed(function () {
    var codes = {}, 
        valid = true;

    // group by code, count occurrences
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.PhoneList(), function (phone) {
        var code = phone.Code();
        codes[code] = codes[code] ? codes[code] + 1 : 1;
        valid = valid && codes[code] === 1;
    });

    return valid;
}).extend({ mustEqual: true });
```

Comment: bit confused i fear i will face some scope issues similar to my previous unanswered post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994704/how-to-access-outer-function-observable-in-inner-function-in-viewmodel

Comment: Scope issues? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: see i need to apply validation to a observable 'code' for every row which is in my function `Phone()` and if i apply a computed as you mentioned in phone function i cant access `self.PhoneList` it gives me undefined .

Comment: Ohh I see, my bad. Try again.

Comment: well i guess you seen my code above where i have `self.validation` inside to that i am using `extend` and doing my observable validation  . so can you hint me how to use that way rather keeping computed in `PhoneViewModel` . am i missing something . cheers

Comment: I just need to know from your expertise have you tried to access observable inside sub-main which is under main function something like `Phone()` in `PhoneViewModel` .

Answer (score 1):

Add the following jQuery in `$(document).ready(function(){});`, and it will show you the repeated text fields:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:submit").click(function () {
        $("input:text").each(function(){
            var index = $(this).index("input:text") % 3;
            var value = $(this).val();
            $("input:text").not(this).each(function(){
                if($(this).index("input:text") % 3 == index && $(this).val() == value && $(this).val()!="")
                    $(this).next().show().text("Repeated");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JL26Z/75/) (with your fiddle).

Comment: awesome and your efforts are appreciated but at any cost i need to deal things in `ko` way . any idea

Comment: Not really, never used that framework before. Can help you with pure javascript/jquery. :)